# extjs adding form contents to another form

Tags: form-submit, javascript-framework, extjs3, formpanel

I have 2 forms,

```
var f1 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

      items: [{ xtype: 'label', text: 'form1'}]
});

var f2 = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

      items: [{ xtype: 'label', text: 'form2'}]
});
```

I want to send form1 's items to form2 so that i only need 1 submit call. Is there any   way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Keep only One submit button and add these two panels by using card or border layout.
On click of submit you collect all the details and if any validation needed do in Submit button click handler and go ahead.

I don't think its so difficult. 
Have a look on layout examples and how to add forms as items.